# Disable App features until user is verified

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, user-controls, customization

I'm developing an app that is like a social network, in which a user after registering cannot interact with other people's profiles until they are verified by the admin, but can do other things.

[For example, they can see other peoples profiles like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AqFg.png)

but cannot click on it, until they are verified.

So there are a lot of other features that need to be disabled in different fragments until the user is verified,

My approach is to toggle the clickable value true/ false of all the buttons, cards, and other
components at a time depending upon whether the user is verified or not.

[This is my approach to this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6KZU.png). But I have no idea how to implement it, Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Set up the database if you haven't done so. Look at [granting permissions on firebase](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000272?hl=en). All you would need to do is retrieve the user doc as they login or open the app and retrieve the `areDocsVerfied` variable. [Tutorial on firestore](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/integrating-firestore-in-android-kotlin/).

Comment: Thanks, the tutorial link was useful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.